# Pagination for category slug returns 404 when page >= 2

Tags: categories, pagination, slug, variables

I have a custom type and the slug is:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'blog/%blogs_tax%'),
```

And after `register_post_type()` I have a function to rewrite the slug variable.

I works fine, but I have problems with pagination...

When I try to access something like http://www.site.com/blog/job/page/2/  (job is the category), I receive 404.

The pagination with simple slug from an another custom type Like : `'slug' => 'cases/'`) works fine... the problem happens only when I use a variable in the slug (%blogs_tax% or another).
How to fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: you can not pass variables like that.

Comment: make sure you're not passing `'pages' => false` for _rewrite_ as it will tell not to use rewrite rules for pagination.

Comment: Amit, it is TRUE value.


   $args = array(
       'labels' => $labels,
       'public' => true,
       'publicly_queryable' => true,
       'show_ui' => true, 
       'show_in_menu' => true, 
       'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'blog/%blogs_tax%', 'pages' => true),
    'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag', 'blogs_tax'),
       'capability_type' => 'post',
       'has_archive' => true, 
       'hierarchical' => true,
       'menu_position' => null,
       'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt')
     );

Answer (score 1):

I got fix this problem with:

```
add_rewrite_rule('blog/([^/]*)/page/([0-9]+)?/?$', 'index.php?post_type=blog&blogs_tax=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', 'top');
```

In functions.php, after `register_post_type`.

Very important: You must flush rules. It is easy to do changing the permalink.